# How to quickly rename all variables in a formula with Z3 (python API)

Tags: python, z3

I am looking for a way to rename all variables in a formula according to a given substitution map. I am currently using the `substitute` function, but it seems to be quite slow.

Is there another function I can use which is faster than it? is there any other way of doing it quickly?

N.B. I am only substituting fresh variables to the variables in the original formula, so there are no renaming clashes. Is there any way to perform the renaming faster under this assumption?

For instance,

```
# given
f = And(Int('x') > Int('y'), Or(Int('x') - 5 >= Int('z'), Int('k') > 1))
# expected result after substitution
# f = And(Int('v0') > Int('v1'), Or(Int('v0') - 5 >= Int('v2'), Int('v3') > 1))
```

Is there any way to do it working on the **context** of `f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an inherently faster way over the API. I have a few comments regarding speed:

1. You seem to be using the Python API, which by itself has a huge overhead. It may help to time
   the portion used in python separately from Z3.
2. The implementation of the substitute function uses class that gets allocated on the stack. 
   It is quite possible that making this class a persisted attribute on the context will 
   speed up amortized time because it will not be allocating and re-allocating memory repeatedly. I would have to profile an instance to be able to tell if this change really pays off.
3. The more fundamental way to perform renaming is to work with implicit renaming, so not apply substitution at all, but access variables with different offsets. This low level way of dereferencing variables is not available in any way over the API or even the way we represent high-level expressions so it is not going to be an option.
4. If your application allows it, you may be able to work with existing terms and encode substitutions implicitly. For example in some applications one can just add equality constraints between old and new variables.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to recode my project in C++ to get advantage of the quickness of the C++ api. If you could provide an example of point 2 I would gladly try to check it out too. I agree on point 3 but since the api does not provide low-level access to the variables of a formula I will not be able to get advantage of it. With regards to point 4 unfortunately my application does not allow this trick.